# Remove Lines from File which appear in another MD5 File

Tags: 14.04, md5sum

I have a large file A (consisting of emails), one line for each mail. I also have another file B that contains another set of mails but in MD5.

Which command would I use to remove all the addresses that exist in md5 file B from the file A.

So, if file A contained:

A

B

C

and file B contained:

9d5ed678fe57bcca610140957afab571

f623e75af30e62bbd73d6df5b50bb7b5

3a3ea00cfc35332cedf6e5e9a32e94da

( those are letters B D E , but in MD5 )

Then file A should be left with:

A

C

Any help would be much appreciated! Somebody will surely come up and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little Python script that will do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import hashlib

with open(sys.argv[2]) as hashfile:
    hashes = set(hashfile.read().splitlines())

with open(sys.argv[1]) as emailfile:
    for email in emailfile:
        email = email.rstrip('\n')
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(email)
        if md5.hexdigest() not in hashes:
            print email
```

Pass it the names of your files as arguments (e.g., `python whatever_name_you_save_it_as.py file_A file_B`), and it will print the output you want.